# DDEV Install "unable to locate the package certutil"

Tags: docker, ddev, certutil, mkcert

I am trying to run Drupal on DDEV.  In an administrative window, I installed mkcert v1.4.4. I have successfully installed Docker, Ubuntu 2204.1.6 and DDEV.  When I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y certutil xdg-utils` in Ubuntu, I receive the message `E: Unable to locate package certutil`

I tried to install certutil using `apt-get install libnss3-tools`, and it also seemed to work, but I am STILL getting the error message when I attempt to install the xdg utilities.

I am using WSL2 on a Windows machine.

Comment: I'm not sure if you edited your question or what, but you can't get an error message about certutil when trying to install libnss3-tools. Please show what you actually did and what the actual result was. You might also try libnss3.

Answer (score 3):

This is a mistake in the docs. It should be libnss3-tools, so `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libnss3-tools xdg-utils` (certutil is installed by libnss3-tools)